RuntimeError - Expected All Tensors on the Same Device (CUDA and CPU)
I am working on a script that runs an offsite prompt tuning model using a pre-trained Vicuna-7b model on GPU (CUDA). However, when I attempt to execute the code, I encounter the above error. It seems the tensors are not all being transferred to the same device.
I'm working on a LLM project, currently the project runs on HPC cluster, GPU Model: A100-40gb.
This is the train_opt.py file that im trying to run:
"""Offsite Prompt Tuning"""
import torch
from copy import deepcopy
import argparse, os
import numpy as np
import wandb
from transformers import set_seed, AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

from utils.utils import make_if_not_exist, str2bool
from utils.template import get_eval_template
from utils.dln import BackwardInstructGenerator
from utils.data import get_dataset
from utils.dp import LDGumbelMechanism, ExpMechanism
from utils.evaluate import Evaluator

CHECKPOINT_ROOT = './checkpoint'

def config_args(parser: argparse.ArgumentParser):
    parser.add_argument('--ape_mode', default='bwd', choices=['bwd', 'iid_ibwd'], type=str,
                        help="bwd: backward update by DLN1, will resample prompts based on the same sets of demos;\n"
                             "iid_ibwd: Will not iteratively update instruct but sample each instruct "\
                             "independently. This is similar to bwd but will use different demos for each iteration.;\n"
                             "Note to use iid_ibwd for dp")
    parser.add_argument('--seed', default=0, type=int, help='random seed')
    parser.add_argument('--data', default='sst2', choices=['sst2', 'trec', 'disaster', 'mpqa'])
    parser.add_argument('--model', default='lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.3', help="model for generating prompts.")
    parser.add_argument('--instruct_type', default='vicuna', type=str, help='instruction format.')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=1, type=int, help="batch size for evaluation")
    parser.add_argument('--holdout_ratio', default=0.01, type=float, help='ratio of training data to be held out for validation.')
    parser.add_argument('--test_ratio', default=1., type=float, help='ratio of testing data to be used.')
    # prompt generation
    parser.add_argument('--steps', default=1, type=int, help='num of iterations of generation. Will iteratively update prompts.')
    parser.add_argument('--num_prompt', default=5, type=int, help='num of prompt to generate')
    parser.add_argument('--num_demos', default=5, type=int, help='num of demos to be used for prompt generation or ICL.')
    parser.add_argument('--balance_demos', default=False, type=str2bool, help='balance demos in meta-prompts. Do not use this for DP cases.')
    parser.add_argument('--max_new_tokens', default=128, type=int, help='max num of tokens for prompt')
    parser.add_argument('--ensemble_gen', default=False, type=str2bool, help='ensemble all meta prompts.')
    parser.add_argument('--ensemble_num', default=205, type=int, help='num of demo subsets for ensemble.')
    parser.add_argument('--gen_batch_size', default=1, type=int, help='batch size when generating prompts.')
    parser.add_argument('--gen_temp', default=0.9, type=float,
                        help='generation temperature on samplng tokens. 1 means no temp. Smaller values means less variance.')
    parser.add_argument('--rep_penalty', default=1., type=float,
                        help='repetition penalty. Larger value, less repetition.')
    parser.add_argument('--rm_eval_item_name', type=str2bool, default=False, help='Remove `Input:` in prompts. Required by DLN-1')
    # dp
    parser.add_argument('--dp_eps', default=None, type=float,
                        help='eps for DP. Recommend value: target_total_eps / max_new_token')
    parser.add_argument('--dp_delta', default=None, type=float,
                        help='delta for DP. Recommend value: target_total_delta / max_new_token')
    parser.add_argument('--target_eps', default=None, type=float,
                        help='target total eps for DP before generation stops.')
    parser.add_argument('--tokenwise_gen', default=False, type=str2bool,
                        help='generate prompt token by token. For each token, the batch of demos will be resampled.')


def render_runname(args):
    """Render args into a single string."""
    args.run_name = f"{args.data}/{args.ape_mode}/{args.model.replace('/', '_')}/" + f"s{args.seed}_pt{args.num_prompt}"
    if args.steps != 1:
        args.run_name += f"_st{args.steps}"
    if args.max_new_tokens != 1024:
        args.run_name += f"_mt{args.max_new_tokens}"
    if args.ensemble_gen:
        args.run_name += f'_ens-gen-{args.ensemble_num}'
        if args.tokenwise_gen:
            args.run_name += f'-twg'
    else:
        assert not args.tokenwise_gen, "Not allow tokenwise_gen for non-ensemble generation. Actually, it is unnecessary and inefficient."
    if args.balance_demos:
        args.run_name += '_bal'
    if args.rm_eval_item_name:
        args.run_name += '_rm-ein'
    # sampling
    args.run_name += f'_temp{args.gen_temp}'
    if args.rep_penalty != 1.:
        args.run_name += f'_rp{args.rep_penalty}'
    # dp
    if args.dp_eps is not None:
        args.run_name += f'_dp{args.dp_eps}d{args.dp_delta}_max{args.target_eps}'
        assert args.ape_mode in ["iid_ibwd"], "Require ape_mode to be `iid_ibwd` which implement the subsampling."
    print(f"Run name: {args.run_name}")

    args.save_path = os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_ROOT, args.run_name)
    make_if_not_exist(args.save_path)
    args.save_file = os.path.join(args.save_path, f"auto_prompt.pth")


def print_estimate_dp(dp_engine, val_dp_engine):
    print(f"DP configurations:")
    print(f"- generation dp")
    # estimate max dp expense based on estimated queries.
    if args.dp_delta * args.subsampling_rate * args.num_prompt * args.max_new_tokens > args.target_delta:
        print(f"  !!WARNING To run the full generation, dp_delta should be smaller "\
                f"than {args.target_delta / (args.subsampling_rate * args.num_prompt * args.max_new_tokens)}")
        print(f"  Estimate max eps by reducing num of gen tokens from " \
                f"{args.num_prompt * args.max_new_tokens} to {int(args.target_delta / args.subsampling_rate / args.dp_delta)}")
        eps, delta = dp_engine.get_dp_expense(int(args.target_delta / args.subsampling_rate / args.dp_delta))
    else:
        eps, delta = dp_engine.get_dp_expense(args.num_prompt * args.max_new_tokens)
    print(f"  estimated max eps: eps={eps:.3f} delta={delta:g}")

    # DP for validation
    print(f"- val dp")
    print(f"  noise scale: {1 / args.target_eps:.4f}")
    val_eps, val_delta = val_dp_engine.get_dp_expense(1, 1)
    print(f"  estimated val eps: eps={val_eps:.3f} delta={val_delta:g}")

def main(arg_list=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # device
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='cuda')
    parser.add_argument('--no_wandb', action='store_true', help='disable wandb')

    parser.add_argument('--skip_eval', action='store_true', help='skip eval on holdout (and ranking) to save time')
    config_args(parser)
    global args
    if arg_list is not None:
        args = parser.parse_args(arg_list)
    else:
        args = parser.parse_args()

    set_seed(args.seed)
    rng = np.random.RandomState(args.seed)

    render_runname(args)
    make_if_not_exist(args.save_path)

    wandb.init(project='dp-opt',
               name=args.run_name, config=vars(args),
               mode='offline' if args.no_wandb else 'online')
    save_dict = {'config': vars(args)}

    # load data
    dataset, label_words = get_dataset(args.data, args.holdout_ratio, args.test_ratio, rng)
    # config DP
    if args.dp_eps is not None:
        n_sample = len(dataset['train'])
        dp_batch_size = args.ensemble_num * args.num_demos
        args.target_delta = 1 / n_sample
        args.subsampling_rate = dp_batch_size / n_sample
        wandb.config['target_delta'] = args.target_delta
        wandb.config['subsampling_rate'] = args.subsampling_rate

        # DP for training
        dp_engine = LDGumbelMechanism(
            args.dp_eps, args.dp_delta,
            target_eps=args.target_eps, target_delta=args.target_delta,
            subsampling_rate=args.subsampling_rate,
            fail_mode='retry')
        val_dp_engine = ExpMechanism(args.target_eps,
                                     target_eps=args.target_eps, target_delta=args.target_delta)
        print_estimate_dp(dp_engine, val_dp_engine)
    else:
        dp_engine = None
        val_dp_engine = None

    # Load model
    model_args = {'revision': 'main'}
    if args.device == 'cuda':
        model_args['device_map'] = 'cuda'
        model_args['torch_dtype'] = torch.float16
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('./vicuna-7b-v1.3/',
                                                #args.model,
                                                low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
                                                offload_folder="offload",
                                                 **model_args)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('./vicuna-7b-v1.3/',
                                                #args.model,
                                                use_fast=False,
                                                revision='main',
                                                device_map='cuda')
    if 'gpt2' in args.model or 'llama' in args.model.lower():
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.padding_side = 'left'
    tokenizer.truncation_side = 'left'
    disable_att_mask =  ('llama' in args.model) or ('vicuna' in args.model)  # llama may have bugs on logits

    # Prepare evaluator
    instruct_type, eval_template, init_instruct = get_eval_template(
        args.model, args.data, add_item_name=not args.rm_eval_item_name, instruct_type=args.instruct_type)
    evaluator = Evaluator(eval_template, label_words, model, tokenizer, dataset, args.batch_size, device=args.device)

    # Prepare instruction generator.
    if args.ape_mode in ['bwd', 'iid_ibwd']:
        instruct_generator = BackwardInstructGenerator(
            model, tokenizer, args.device, args.max_new_tokens,
            label_words, instruct_type, ensemble_gen=args.ensemble_gen,
            disable_att_mask=disable_att_mask, gen_batch_size=args.gen_batch_size,
            gen_temperature=args.gen_temp,
            rep_penalty=args.rep_penalty,
            dp_engine=dp_engine,
            balance_demos=args.balance_demos,
            tokenwise_gen=args.tokenwise_gen,
            )
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f'ape_mode: {args.ape_mode}')

    best_holdout_acc = 0
    global_best_holdout_test_acc = 0
    do_early_stop_cnt = 2 if args.steps > 1 else 1
    best_save_dict = {}
    for step in range(args.steps):
        print("\n\n"+ "="*20+"\n"+"="*3 + f"  Step {step}  " + "="*3 + "\n"+ "="*20 + "\n")
        # Step 1: generate prompts
        if args.ape_mode == 'bwd':
            # each instruction will be sampled from the same demonstration set.
            generated_instructs, used_demos = instruct_generator.generate_instruct_bwd(
                init_instruct, args.num_demos, dataset['train'], rng, evaluator,
                num_prompt=args.num_prompt,
                num_meta_prompt=args.ensemble_num if args.ensemble_gen else None
            )
        elif args.ape_mode == 'iid_ibwd':
            # each instruction will be sampled from the non-overlap (iid) demonstration sets.
            generated_instructs, used_demos = instruct_generator.iterative_generate(
                init_instruct, args.num_demos, dataset['train'], rng, evaluator,
                num_prompt=args.num_prompt,
                num_meta_prompt=args.ensemble_num if args.ensemble_gen else None,
                verbose=not args.ensemble_gen,
                iid_instruct=True,  # will make each instruct generated independently.
            )
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"Unknown ape_mode: {args.ape_mode}")

        # process generated instructions.
        assert len(generated_instructs) >= 1, "Fail to generate instructions."
        if val_dp_engine is None:
            save_dict['all generated_instructs'] = generated_instructs
            unique_instructs = list(set(generated_instructs))
            if len(unique_instructs) < len(generated_instructs):
                print(f"Found duplicated instructs with {len(unique_instructs)}/{len(generated_instructs)} unique prompts.")
                print(f"Removed duplicated instructs.")
                generated_instructs = unique_instructs

        # log & save
        if dp_engine is not None:
            final_eps, final_delta = dp_engine.get_dp_expense()
            wandb.summary['final eps'] = final_eps
            wandb.summary['final delta'] = final_delta
            print(f"Final DP: eps={final_eps:.3f}, delta={final_delta}")
        else:
            final_eps, final_delta = 0., 0.
        save_dict['generated_instructs'] = generated_instructs
        save_dict['used_demos'] = used_demos
        torch.save(save_dict, args.save_file)
        print(f"save results => {args.save_file}")

        if not args.skip_eval or args.steps > 1:
            # Step 2: Evaluate and find the best instruct
            instruct_metrics, save_dict = evaluator.find_best_instruct(generated_instructs, save_dict, dp_engine=val_dp_engine)
            best_holdout_idx = save_dict['best_holdout_idx']
            step_best_holdout_acc = instruct_metrics['holdout acc'][best_holdout_idx]

            if val_dp_engine is not None:
                val_eps, val_delta = val_dp_engine.get_dp_expense()
                if val_eps > final_eps:
                    final_eps = val_eps
                if val_delta > final_delta:
                    final_delta = val_delta
                wandb.summary['final eps'] = final_eps
                wandb.summary['final delta'] = final_delta
                print(f"Final DP w/ val: eps={final_eps}, delta: {final_delta}")

            # save
            torch.save(save_dict, args.save_file)
            print(f"save results => {args.save_file}")

            if step_best_holdout_acc > best_holdout_acc:
                print(f"best holdout acc changed: from {best_holdout_acc} to {step_best_holdout_acc}")
                print(f"\nUpdate instruct from\n[START]{init_instruct}[END]")
                init_instruct = generated_instructs[best_holdout_idx]
                print(f"to the selected instruct\n[START]{init_instruct}[END]")
                best_holdout_acc = step_best_holdout_acc
                global_best_holdout_test_acc = save_dict['best_holdout_test_acc']
                best_save_dict = deepcopy(save_dict)
            else:
                print(f"\nUnchanged best instruct:\n[START]{init_instruct}[END]")
                print(f" Unchanged best_holdout_acc: {best_holdout_acc}")
                do_early_stop_cnt -= 1
                print(f"Will early stop in {do_early_stop_cnt} more unchanged.")
                # move to last
                torch.save(save_dict, os.path.join(args.save_path, f"last.pth"))
                # restore the best to the default file.
                torch.save(best_save_dict, args.save_file)
            wandb.log({
                'step': step,
                'best_holdout_acc': best_holdout_acc,
                'step_best_holdout_acc': step_best_holdout_acc,
                'step_test_acc': save_dict['best_holdout_test_acc'],
                'global_best_holdout_test_acc': global_best_holdout_test_acc,
            })

            if do_early_stop_cnt == 0:
                print(f"Early stop at step {step}/{args.steps}...")
                break
    return best_save_dict, save_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The error im facing is :
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
Entire terminal output:
Run name: sst2/iid_ibwd/lmsys_vicuna-7b-v1.3/s0_pt40_mt50_ens-gen-205_temp1.1
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████| 2/2 [00:57<00:00, 28.88s/it]
You are using the default legacy behaviour of the <class 'transformers.models.llama.tokenization_llama.LlamaTokenizer'>. This is expected, and simply means that the `legacy` (previous) behavior will be used so nothing changes for you. If you want to use the new behaviour, set `legacy=False`. This should only be set if you understand what it means, and thoroughly read the reason why this was added as explained in https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/24565 - if you loaded a llama tokenizer from a GGUF file you can ignore this message


====================
===  Step 0  ===
====================

dln-fwd:   0%|          | 0/66676 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Starting from v4.46, the `logits` model output will have the same type as the model (except at train time, where it will always be FP32)
dln-fwd: 100%|██████████| 66676/66676 [34:37<00:00, 32.09it/s, acc: 0.858]
[Iter 0/40] generating  prompt

>>> Meta prompt #0:
[START]A student is completing a task that requires producing a text output from a text input. The student receives an instruction that describes how to produce the output given each input. The student has made some errors. Your task is to improve the instruction such that the student can fix the errors.
This was the instruction.

Instruction: Classify the input text as positive or negative.

# Student successes
Input: it's almost impossible not to be swept away by the sheer beauty of his images .
Correct Output: positive

Input: a sick , twisted sort of way
Correct Output: negative

Input: an elegant film with often surprising twists and an intermingling of naiveté and sophistication
Correct Output: positive

Input: is trying to dupe the viewer into taking it all as very important simply because the movie is ugly to look at and not a hollywood product
Correct Output: negative

# Student errors
Input: on a 10-year delay
Student Output: negative
Correct Ouput: positive

Improve the instruction to fix the student errors. Clarify the instruction by adding few words or a short sentence. Be concise
Improved Instruction: [APE][END]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/train_opt.py", line 301, in <module>
    main()
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/train_opt.py", line 216, in main
    generated_instructs, used_demos = instruct_generator.iterative_generate(
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/dln.py", line 242, in iterative_generate
    _generated_instructs, _used_demos = self.generate_instruct_bwd(cur_instruct, num_demos, dataset, rng, evaluator, num_prompt=1, num_meta_prompt=num_meta_prompt, **kwargs)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/dln.py", line 280, in generate_instruct_bwd
    return self._generate_instruct_bwd(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/dln.py", line 409, in _generate_instruct_bwd
    instructs = self.forward_generate_prompt(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/dln.py", line 128, in forward_generate_prompt
    smp_output_ids = ensemble_generate(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/ensemble.py", line 84, in ensemble_generate
    output_ids = greedy_search(model, input_ids, attention_mask, eos_token_id, pad_token_id,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lustre06/project/6097055/ombh/DP-OPT/utils/ensemble.py", line 191, in greedy_search
    next_token_scores = logits_processor(cur_input_ids, next_token_logits)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ombh/envs/DP-OPT/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/logits_process.py", line 104, in __call__
    scores = processor(input_ids, scores)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ombh/envs/DP-OPT/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/logits_process.py", line 163, in __call__
    eos_token_mask = isin_mps_friendly(vocab_tensor, self.eos_token_id)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/ombh/envs/DP-OPT/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/pytorch_utils.py", line 328, in isin_mps_friendly
    return torch.isin(elements, test_elements)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument test_elements in method wrapper_CUDA_isin_Tensor_Tensor)

What could be causing this error? How should I proceed with debugging or fixing this issue?

Where is args.device defined in your code ? Some of your model choose their device according to this value and some have a hardcoded 'cuda' value which is likely to cause the issue you are facing. To facilitate debugging, can you prune the parts of the code that are not relevant ? In general, try to prune your code down to the minimal amount that can still reproduce your error. And you can print the device of all your tensors to check that they all match

@trialNerror Thank you for your reply.
parser.add_argument('--device', default='cuda')
Above line defines the args.device as "cuda" as default. Thus, i dont exactly need to  define it when I'm running the code. Even if i do pass it as an argument, it returns the same error as described in the post.
For example, "python train_opt.pt ... --device=cuda" returns the same error as described above.
